# $2$-norm of orthogonal transformation on subgaussian vector

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, stiefel-manifolds

Suppose we have a vector $e\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and a matrix $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ such that $Q^{\top}Q=I_p$, i.e., the columns of $Q$ are orthornormal. Specifically, $e$ has i.i.d. subgaussian entries with mean zero and parameter $\sigma$.

Now I want to figure out the relationship between $\Vert Q^{\top}e\Vert_{2}$ and  $\Vert e\Vert_{2}$ in order to find the Orlicz norm of the former norm. However, I get stuck in
$$\Vert Q^{\top}e\Vert_{2}^2=e^{\top}QQ^{\top}e$$

and do not know what to do further. I want to derive a form like $$\Vert Q^{\top}e\Vert_{2}^2\leqslant c\Vert e\Vert_2^2.$$

And I want to ask does the constant $c$ depend on $n$? I appreciate for your help.

Comment: This constant $c$ is given by the largest absolute value of the (possibly complex) eigenvalues if $Q^T$. All of its Eigenvalues must necessarily have absolute value $1$, so $c=1$, which is dimension-independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ${\bf Q} {\bf Q}^\top$ is a [projection matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix), its eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$. Thus,

$$ \left\| {\bf Q}^\top {\bf v} \right\|_2^2 = {\bf v}^\top {\bf Q} {\bf Q}^\top {\bf v} \leq \underbrace{\lambda_{\max} \left( {\bf Q} {\bf Q}^\top \right)}_{= 1} \left\|  {\bf v} \right\|_2^2 $$

Comment: I think this is a right answer, but is the bound tight? For example, suppose that Q is diag(1, 0, ... ,0). Then the LHS is the square of the first element of v, the RHS is a summation of n squared elements. I want the RHS change with respect to the rank of Q.

Comment: @TNLI Try ${\bf v} = (v_1,0,\dots, 0)$. The rank of a projection matrix is its trace.